# How do I retrieve the sum of 2 large numbers?

Tags: assembly, x86-16, emu8086

I am trying to add two numbers (lets say the first number = 200 and the second = 100). When I add them in AL, I get 2C in hex instead of 300. Is it because there's an overflow? and if that is the cause of it, how do I get the output from it? I read from several other posts but most of them deal with smaller numbers or use xor, which I didnt really understand why it is used at all. Answers are appreciated.

Here's my code:

```
.model small          
.stack 100
.data

    No1 DB 200          ;First number 
    No2 DB 100

    Sum DW ?   

.code  
START: 

    MOV ax, @data
    MOV ds, ax

    MOV ax, 0
    MOV al, No1
    ADD al, No2 

end start
```

Comment: Yes, overflow. You could use 16-bit registers to add them. Include `mov bx, 0`, then after `mov al, No1` then do `mov bl, No2` and `add ax, bx`. Now your `1C2` answer is in `ax`. You could use `xor` to zero out a register rather than moving 0 to the register. E.g., `xor ax,ax` zeroes out `ax`. That's because when a bit is xor'ed with itself, you get a 0 bit.

Comment: @lurker I did what you said and it worked! Thank you ^^

Answer (score 1):

Here is a working solution for `emu8086`:

```
.MODEL small          
.STACK 100

.DATA
    No1 DB 200
    No2 DB 100
    Sum DW ?   

.CODE  
   start PROC
      MOV ax, @data
      MOV ds, ax

      XOR ah, ah
      MOV al, No1 
      XOR bh, bh
      MOV bl, No2
      ADD ax, bx

      MOV Sum, ax
   start ENDP
```